# alarm is not repeat every 5 minuts in android

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager

I want to repeat alarm every 5 minuts but not working. my code is

```
        hour = timePicker.getCurrentHour();
            minuts = timePicker.getCurrentMinute();
            Log.i("hour" + hour, "minits" + minuts);

            calSet.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
            calSet.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minuts);
            calSet.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            calSet.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND,0);

            Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),
                    AlarmBroadcastReceiver.class);
            final int _id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();

            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                    getBaseContext(), _id, intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

            if (snooze.isChecked()) {
                alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                        calSet.getTimeInMillis(), 5*60*1000, pendingIntent);
            } else {

                 alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                         calSet.getTimeInMillis(),pendingIntent);
            }
```

alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calSet.getTimeInMillis(), 5*1000,pendingIntent);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calSet.getTimeInMillis(), 5*60*1000, pendingIntent);
```